React native error with trying to export my project, getting errors when trying to use ./gradlew bundleRelease
When i used ./gradlew bundleRelease
i got this error

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.
A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Duplicate class com.facebook.react.flipper.ReactNativeFlipper found in modules jetified-flipper-integration-0.73-release.7-release-runtime (com.facebook.react:flipper-integration:0.73.7) and jetified-react-android-0.74-release.1-release-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-android:0.74.1)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.


When i use the 0.74.1 version it does not work, what should i do? stuck with this for a long time, tried ./gradlew clean but that didn't work.
Would love if some help me, been struck for like 3 days trying to export my app i am keep on getting errors.
I mentioned
implementation("com.facebook.react:flipper-intergration:0.73.7")
in my andriod/app/build.gradle
P.S; i use linux (arch)

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/36362#issuecomment-1456325147
you should try this solution, hope it help you.
